# How can i backup my database with lashes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, helper, database-backups

Hello i wish someone can help me it's my presentation tomorrow i would like to ask why does my values does not have lashes? ``` when i backup my database in php? i'm using codeigniter can someone please help me whenever i back up it it turns

```
INSERT INTO `discount` (`id`, `name`, `discount_percent`, `active`) VALUES (3, Student, 10, 1);
```

and it's giving me an error i think he want the value have lashes like this

```
INSERT INTO `discount` (`id`, `name`, `discount_percent`, `active`) VALUES ('3', 'Student', '10', '1');`
```

i tried the first one in my localhost but failed and the second one with lashes is successful so how can i backup with lashes?

my code is:

```
public function create()
{
    // Load the DB utility class
    $this->load->dbutil();
    
    $test = date('YmdS-His');
    // Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
    $config = array (
        'format' => 'zip', // gzip, zip, txt
        'filename' => 'bubblebee_'.$test.'_db.sql', // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
        'add_drop' => TRUE, // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
        'add_insert' => TRUE, // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
        'newline' => "\n", // Newline character used in backup file
        'foreign_key_checks' => FALSE,
    );

   $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($config);
   $db_name ='bubblebee_'.$test.'.zip';
   $this->load->helper('download');
   force_download($db_name, $backup);
}
```

Comment: by "lashes" do you mean "quote marks" (i.e. the `'` character)?

Comment: Why don't you just make a backup direct from mysql? Or is demonstrating how to make a backup using codeigniter supposed to be part of your presentation?

Comment: This seems to have been a known bug in CI - https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5276 - Last comment: _"you can upgrade your CI to the last stable version from this github, then database backup works properly."_ If you don't have the last stable version, upgrade. If already do, then check if there is a new github issue, or create a new. Not much we can help with here though, unfortunately.